# Need to find number of logins each week

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections. I am trying to find the count of logins based upon a LoggedTime field.
I would like to get the no of logins per week for past five weeks.

I have two collections.

collection 1 : Role
Fields : Role, UserName , loggedTime

collection 2 :mysite
Fields : userName ,userEmail ,name

In collection 1, eg:

```
{
'Role' :"admin"
'UserName' : "abc.efg",
'loggedTime' : 2020-06-24T18:12:03.455Z,
}
```

In collection 2, eg:

```
{
'userName' : "abc Mr, efg" ,
'userEmail' : "abc.efg@company.com" ,
'name' : 'orgname'
}
```

Is there any way where we can have a new collection which has the count of the number of logins (based on loggedTime) per week by each orgname for past 5 weeks?

Basically trying to get result like
collection 3:

```
{
name :'orgname',
'Logins current week':'no of logins'
'Logins previous week' : 'no of logins'
'Logins 3rd week' :'no of logins'
'Logins 4th week' :'no of logins'
'Logins 5th week': 'no of logins'
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation).  Perhaps a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_aggregation.htm) to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use various aggregation pipeline stages to transform your data.

[MongoDB’s aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) is modeled on the concept of data processing pipelines. Documents enter a multi-stage pipeline that transforms the documents into an aggregated result.

Your use case can be achieved using following stages and operators in the aggregation pipeline:

1. Perform [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join both collections
2. Using [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), find count of logins by grouping based on week and org name
3. [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) is used to get week difference between current week and week available in `loggedTime`
4. [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) is used to do grouping based on each week for past 5 weeks
5. Finally, transforming the data into required format

> See the working example: [MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GJrYaWxM3Yy)

```
db.Role.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "mysite",
      let: {
        "userName": "$UserName"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            "$expr": {
              "$ne": [
                {
                  "$indexOfCP": [
                    "$userEmail",
                    "$$userName"
                  ]
                },
                -1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "mysite"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$mysite"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        week: {
          $week: "$loggedTime"
        },
        org: "$mysite.name"
      },
      documentCount: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "currentWeek": {
        $week: "$$NOW"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      dateDifference: {
        $subtract: [
          "$currentWeek",
          "$_id.week"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      current: [
        {
          $match: {
            dateDifference: 0
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "name": "$_id.org",
            _id: 0,
            "Loginscurrentweek": "$documentCount"
          }
        }
      ],
      previous: [
        {
          $match: {
            dateDifference: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "name": "$_id.org",
            _id: 0,
            "Loginspreviousweek": "$documentCount"
          }
        }
      ],
      third: [
        {
          $match: {
            dateDifference: 2
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "name": "$_id.org",
            _id: 0,
            "Logins3rdweek": "$documentCount"
          }
        }
      ],
      fourth: [
        {
          $match: {
            dateDifference: 3
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "name": "$_id.org",
            _id: 0,
            "Logins4thweek": "$documentCount"
          }
        }
      ],
      fifth: [
        {
          $match: {
            dateDifference: 4
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            "name": "$_id.org",
            _id: 0,
            "Logins5thweek": "$documentCount"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "givenWeeks": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$current",
          "$fifth",
          "$fourth",
          "$third",
          "$previous"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$givenWeeks"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$givenWeeks.name",
      val: {
        $push: {
          "Loginscurrentweek": "$givenWeeks.Loginscurrentweek",
          "Loginspreviousweek": "$givenWeeks.Loginspreviousweek",
          "Logins3rdweek": "$givenWeeks.Logins3rdweek",
          "Logins4thweek": "$givenWeeks.Logins4thweek",
          "Logins5thweek": "$givenWeeks.Logins5thweek",
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "name": "$_id",
      _id: 0,
      val: {
        "$mergeObjects": "$val"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      name: 1,
      "Logins current week": "$val.Loginscurrentweek",
      "Logins previous week": "$val.Loginspreviousweek",
      "Logins 3rd week": "$val.Logins3rdweek",
      "Logins 4th week": "$val.Logins4thweek",
      "Logins 5th week": "$val.Logins5thweek"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: @Ad1995 Let me know if you need more detailed explanation

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the help...The query is really useful except that when there are duplicate records(same name,same org in collection 2),then the count gets doubled. Other than that the query was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at the aggregation framework to achieve this.
Specifically, given your given data sample:

- $lookup to get the org from the username (and $unwind to cleanup lookup output)
- $group to actually get the logins per week per org
- $out to dump it into a new collection (or just deal with the output and insert it yourself)

See the aggregation pipeline documentation for this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

Here's some sample code to help you along. https://mongoplayground.net/p/htgEekzJmtj
Note that this doesn't output to a new collection yet, nor does it handle "previous, 3rd, ...".

```js
db={
  "logins": [
    {
      "role": "admin",
      "userName": "abc",
      "loggedTime": new Date("2020-06-24T18:12:03.455Z")
    },
    {
      "role": "admin",
      "userName": "abc",
      "loggedTime": new Date("2020-06-24T19:12:03.455Z")
    },
    {
      "role": "admin",
      "userName": "xyz",
      "loggedTime": new Date("2020-07-24T19:12:03.455Z")
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "userName": "abc",
      "userEmail": "abc@abc.com",
      "org": "abc"
    },
    {
      "userName": "xyz",
      "userEmail": "xyz@xyz.com",
      "org": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
db.logins.aggregate([
  {
    /** lookup the org using username*/
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "userName",
      "foreignField": "userName",
      "as": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    /** lookup creates an array of results,*/
    /** we should only have one with current data*/
    /** so we can just unwind it*/
    "$unwind": "$user"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        /** group by year, week and org*/
        year: {
          $year: "$loggedTime"
        },
        week: {
          $week: "$loggedTime"
        },
        org: "$user.org"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
]);
```